# Why TLS allows a certificate issued to a different subdomain?

Tags: http, ssl, browser

I've recently found something that questions everything I thought I knew about TLS.

This website https://int.lyve-lyon.alpha.grandlyon.com is secured with TLS but the certificate is actually issued to *rec.lyve-lyon.alpha.grandlyon.com*.

How can the server submit a certificate issued for a different host, and how can the browser not throw a TLS error? It looks like the certificate behaves like a wildcard one and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Subject Alternative Name (SAN) is an extension to X.509 that allows
> various values to be associated with a security certificate using a
> subjectAltName field. These values are called Subject Alternative
> Names (SANs). Names include:
>
> 1. Email addresses
> 2. IP addresses
> 3. URIs
> 4. **DNS names (this is usually also provided as the Common Name RDN within the Subject field of the main certificate.)**
> 5. directory names (alternative Distinguished Names to that given in the Subject)
> 6. other names, given as a General Name: a registered[3] object identifier    followed by a value
>
> from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name

[image]